# Referenced node as menu item

Tags: 7, routes, users

is it possible to create a menu item that links to the node that references the current user? I can create a more or less suitable solution with views: a page that contains the referenced node but it'd be more user friendly if the menu link contained the URL of this node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Menu token](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_token)

> Menu Token module provides tokens, that could be used in title or in
>   path of menu items (links). For example, if you create a menu item
>   with path: "user/[current-user:uid]", the url will be changed "on fly"
>   to: "user/1" (assuming you are user 1).
>
> Tokens are provided by Token module. Menu Token allows to use both
>   global tokens and entity ones: node, user, term, etc. Entity tokens
>   have several methods of substitution: from context, random and user
>   defined.

If that does not work, you will have to do a custom redirect, either in code or using page manager (part of [ctools](https://www.drupal.org/project/ctools))

Comment: Thanks a lot. As far as I see, Page Manager should do the job but I couldn't make it recognise the user reference field so far.

Comment: Thanks again. Finally I managed to fix the custom page created by the Page Manager: I created a Views context which provided the necessary node ID.